# Is there a widget option in trading view for rotating the chart 90 degrees?

Tags: angular, typescript, tradingview-api

In my Angular project, I'm using the trading view chart with the `widgetOptions` in ts file looking like this:

```
    const widgetOptions: any = {
      autosize: true,
      charts_storage_url: 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
      charts_storage_api_version: '1.1',
      container_id: 'chartContainer',
      datafeed,
      debug: false,
      disabled_features: ['use_localstorage_for_settings'],
      enabled_features: [],
      enable_publishing: false,
      fullscreen: true,
      hide_legend: true,
      interval: 'D',
      library_path: 'assets/tradingview/charting_library/',
      locale: this._locale,
      numeric_formatting: { decimal_sign: ',' },
      save_image: false,
      symbol,
      theme: this._theme,
      timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
      toolbar_bg: this._theme === 'dark' ? '#0d131e' : '#fff',
      user_id: this._authService.decodedToken?.email || 'public_user',

      overrides: Object.assign(
        OVERRIDES,
        this._theme === 'dark' ? DARK_OVERRIDES : LIGHT_OVERRIDES
      ),
    };
```

My question is, is there anything in widgetOptions I can use so I can rotate the chart 90 degrees? I'm aware that I can achieve this using css but I'm specifically asking about the widgetOptions object.